# bootstrap typeahead selector for dynamic page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

When I load a page normally and use this code :

```
$('#clientName').typeahead({
   //removed options since they are not needed for my question
});
```

The typeahead works fine on #clientName.
But when I load the input #clientName dynamically via AJAX then the above code doesn't work.

Is there some way to let it work?

It's equal to this problem :

```
$('#randomDiv').click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

This one only works if the content is not dynamically loaded. But this code will work :

```
$(document).on('click','#randomDiv',function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");   
});
```

So I would like to add the handler to the document or body, and not to the #clientName div itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only have the choice to call `$('#clientName').typeahead(...);` again after inserting the `input` with the id *clientName* dynamically. If you capsules calling `typehead` into a function, you need only to call the function again without setting all options again.

Comment: yeah I was afraid that that would be my only option.. thanks though

Comment: Unfortunately there is no event that is triggered on modified HTML.

Comment: scessor, i edited my question. Do you know any reason for that?

Comment: During the alert is waiting for user prompt other scripts (like an ajax response) can be executed. I think you're calling the function to early, are you sure the html is changed before you're calling the function?

Comment: If the problem still exists, please show us your code calling the ajax and calling the function `clientNametypeahead()`.